# for loop doesn't receive full data

Tags: java, socket.io, serversocket

I got the problem that my program is stuck in the for loop because the dataInputSteam doesn't receive all data before the DataOutputSteam is finished.
In my program I want to send a secreenshot with the server and the client should receive it:
Server:

```
public sendScreen(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Robot robot;
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
            Dimension screenSize  = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            Rectangle screen = new Rectangle( screenSize );
            BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture( screen );

            BufferedImage scaledImage = Scalr.resize(image, 300);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
            byte[] screenBytes = baos.toByteArray();


            daos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            daos.writeInt(screenBytes.length);
            daos.write(screenBytes);
            System.out.println("Screen sent");
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

And the client:

```
public static class GetScreenshot implements Runnable{

    Socket socket;
    private static DataInputStream din;
    private static BufferedImage screenshot;

    public GetScreenshot(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("start method getScreenshot");
        int length;
        byte[] buffer;
        PrintWriter out;

        try {
            //sending command to send screenshot
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            out.println("GETSCREENSHOT");

            din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("DIS created");
            length = din.readInt();
            System.out.println("Got data from DIS");
            buffer = new byte[length];
            System.out.println("Filled buffer");
            for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
                buffer[i] = (byte) din.read();
                System.out.println("read" + i+ "while length is " + length + " read data " + buffer);
            }
            System.out.println("got buffer");
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);

            screenshot = ImageIO.read(bais);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //writing screenshot to local disk
        File outputfile = new File("C:\\users\\XXXX\\documents\\image2.png");
        try {
            ImageIO.write(screenshot, "png", outputfile);
            System.out.println("image written to local disk");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //set screenshot in the tool
        Main.labelScreenshot.setIcon(new ImageIcon(screenshot));
    }

}
```

Does anybody know how i can transfer all of the data of the screenshot?

Greetings
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is because your view (canvas/label/etc) width & height is smaller than your image. Try to resize the screenshoot so the width & height is same as your view (canvas/label/etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
buffer = new byte[length];
System.out.println("Filled buffer");
```

At this point this message is simply untrue. You have created the buffer, but you certainly haven't filled it.

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    buffer[i] = (byte) din.read();
    System.out.println("read" + i+ "while length is " + length + " read data " + buffer);
}
```

All this is equivalent to:

```
din.readFully(buffer);
```

And then:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
screenshot = ImageIO.read(bais);
//writing screenshot to local disk
File outputfile = new File("C:\\users\\XXXX\\documents\\image2.png");
try {
    ImageIO.write(screenshot, "png", outputfile);
```

All this is entirely equivalent to:

```
try (new FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\users\\XXXX\\documents\\image2.png"))
{
    out.write(buffer);
}
```

There is no need to decode and re-encode the image.

Answer (score -1):

You add this to the sender part:

```
socket.flush();
```

if not worked, then:

```
socket.shutdownOutput();
```

Comment: There is no such method as `Socket.flush()`. There is a `Socket.getOutputStream().flush()`, but it doesn't do anything. `Socket.shutdownOutput()` would mean that nothing further could be sent on the socket: it isn't clear from the OP's question that that is a permissible constraint.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for the quick answers. `Socket.flush();` or `Socket.getOutputStream().flush()` does't work, `socket.shutdownOutput();` closes the stream. Because i want to send more data I would like to keep the socket open so this is also not the way I can go. Are there any other ways I could solve that?

Comment: Sorry, for `socket.flush()` I mean that you flush the `daos`. I had the same problem which I solved that just by `socket.shutdownOutput();'. And also you can try `din.read(buffer);`. You can try it, good luck!

Comment: `DataOutputStream.flush()` doesnt' do anything either. It flushes the underlying `OutputStream`, which in this case is the socket output stream, whose `flush()` method doesn't do anything either, as already stated. Clearly *you* haven't tried it.

Comment: If you don't want to close the socket, then in this which you write your code is NOT OK.

Comment: Rubbish. You can transfer hundreds of files using this technique. If you're going to make wild claims like this, please provide some supporting argument or evidence.

Comment: I say this because I did not see any loop that continuously send the data,  not in the sender and not in the receiver part. So I think that you just send only once.

Comment: It's not OK not to close the socket. It is OK not to close it if you are sending more than one file. You need to make yourself clear.